# Site not scaling in iPad Portrait and mobile landscape

Tags: css, html, ipad, responsive-design, viewport

I been trying to get the site to scale to fit on Portrait in iPad but to no avail .. this is my meta :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

also added this to script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
        viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=980');
    }
</script>
```

and on my CSS in Queries I tried this:

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 768px) and ( max-width: 1024px ) {
    body {min-width: 980px;}
}
```

basing on what I saw here:

[iPad not scaling site down website correctly in portrait orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944205/ipad-not-scaling-site-down-website-correctly-in-portrait-orientation)

I tried height too, but to no avail...

There was also an a similar question here:

[Safari on iPad Does Not Fit 980px Width Site in Portrait Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104266/safari-on-ipad-does-not-fit-980px-width-site-in-portrait-mode)

But to be honest i didn't understand if there is even an answer(I'm not taking viewport off..)...

As I mentioned, looking good but in portrait I have to slide to the left to see the whole thing. and lastly in mobile it fits perfectly in 320 but when landscape it still stays at 320 so I assume it might be the **same case in scaling**....I assume I didn't have to use %....but is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe due to the old "[orientation problem](http://adactio.com/journal/4470/)".

you may want to try this codes:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
if (viewportmeta) {
    viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
            viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
        }, false);
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Yes I have this script already but it seems to still cause the issue....I checked some very big company sites and they also have this issue....so might not have to go crazy over this...the only one that looks accurate is adobe site but they use a loooot of %...

Comment: Thanks for your help I will approve this because wasn't the answer I need but was close.

Answer (score 1):

Is it this iOS <5.1 scaling bug that's the issue - 
http://adactio.com/journal/5088/ ?

This is fixed in iOS6 but if you'd need it for an older device you could try -

http://www.blog.highub.com/mobile-2/a-fix-for-iphone-viewport-scale-bug/

or https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix

Comment: Hmm let me review this because : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` when refresh in portrait it WORKS! but once i go to landscape(it zooms a little)... and then go back to portrait it stays on zoom at 768px (I can't even scale it down after that!) :(